# How do I pass string parameters from django to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

I have a problem calling a function with string parameters obtained from python.

python_var **->** html calls the function of js with parameters obtained from python context **->** js file

Browser console says: Uncaught ReferenceError

I am using Django template language to get the variable which is defined as a string in python.

> foo.html
>
> ```py
> <script>
>  libcharts_predict_k( {{title|safe}}, {{data|safe}})
> </script>
> ```

I am sure the problem is only with Strings in JS function parameters because with arrays and numbers I didn't have any problem.
Browser tries to reference something but I am giving as a value

> view.py
>
> ```py
> def second_view(request):
>     title = "A long title"
>     data= df['value'].values.tolist()
>     context = {
>                'data': data,
>                'title': title
>                }
> return (request, 'app/foo.html', context=context)
> ```
>
> *(Imports are fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: put quotes around your template vars:

```
libcharts_predict_k("{{title|safe}}", "{{data|safe}}")
```

And since `data` is a list you want to jsonify it before (in your view):

```
import json

# ....

data = json.dumps(df['value'].values.tolist())
```

Comment: Ok I tried ```python
libcharts_predict_kilos_ventas_familia( '{{titulo|safe}}',{{data|safe}}) ``` and it works, thanks for the idea!

Comment: cf the edit (added after you posted your view code)